# How to multiply in the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How to multiply in the View? Or have  best Practices? Project - car rental.
My controller takes parameter int numberDays.
I need to calculate the total price on View for all days . Need multiply the price in one day the number of days.  And then this parameter must be passed in the form of a controller.

```
public ActionResult DayView(int numberDays)
{
         //
}
```

In View in foreach I display numbercar,colorcar and other...

```
@model IEnumerable<Car>
foreach (Car car in Model)
{
    //other parameters
    <p>Full Price</p>:Model.CostOneDay      //need multiply numberDays
}
```

How `<p>Full Price</p>:@(car.CostOneDay * Model.NumberOfDays)` this parameter add in hiddenfor , I need pass this form to controller

Comment: Instead of your model being an `IEnumerable<Car>` you can define a custom class which extends that to have the additional properties. At that point, you just access the property.

Comment: Yes, what @EricHotinger said. The new class would then be a [ViewModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: You could use a [calculated property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030636/c-sharp-read-only-calculated-properties-should-they-be-methods) in your model but I find that these only end up causing more problems than they solve in the long run. Just get your controller to calculate it into a VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view model class that contains `Cars` and `NumberOfDays`  property

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfDays { get; set; }
}
```

then use it in your controller and pass it to the view

```
public ActionResult DayView(int numberDays)
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
    model.NumberOfDays = numberDays;
    model.Cars = ...; // get the car records here

    return View(model);
}
```

and change your view as below

```
@model MyViewModel
foreach (Car car in Model.Cars)
{
    //other parameters
    <p>Full Price</p>:@(car.CostOneDay * Model.NumberOfDays)
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use the multiplied price in `@Html.HiddenFor`, then you need to add an additional property to your `Car` class. Assuming the type of `CostOneDay` is decimal, add `FullPrice` property with decimal type

```
public class Car
{
    // other properties

    public decimal FullPrice { get; set; }
}
```

then set the `FullPrice` property for each car record in the controller

```
public ActionResult DayView(int numberDays)
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
    model.NumberOfDays = numberDays;
    model.Cars = ...; // get the car records here

    foreach (var car in model.Cars)
    {
        car.FullPrice = car.CostOneDay * model.NumberOfDays;
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

and use `@Html.HiddenFor` like below

```
@model MyViewModel
foreach (Car car in Model.Cars)
{
    //other parameters
    <p>Full Price</p>:@car.FullPrice
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => car.FullPrice)
}
```

Comment: Great!!Thanks! and how now add @(car.CostOneDay * Model.NumberOfDays)   in hiddenFor? I need to pass this form from controler

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment I posted, right now your controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult DayView(int numberDays)
{
  // returns View with IEnumerable
}
```

You want to change this to be something like this, utilizing a new class, `CalculatedDayViewModel` (name this better) -- and have that class hold the calculated fields as properties. Be sure to set up a constructor which allows you to pass in `numberDays` and do the calculation.

```
public ActionResult DayView(int numberDays)
{
  return View(new CalculatedDayViewModel(numberDays));
}
```

Then in your Razor, change `@model IEnumerable<Car>` to be `@model CalculatedDayViewModel` and you'll have access to the calculated properties.